# quicklisp-client:quickload is undefined

Tags: quicklisp, slimv

I installed quicklisp in slimv and quickload doesn't seem to be working.

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload "hunchentoot")
The function QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD is undefined.
```

apropos works so I'm not sure what went wrong.

```
CL-USER> (ql:system-apropos "hunchentoot")         
#<SYSTEM clack-handler-hunchentoot / clack-20121013-git / quicklisp 2012-10-13> 
#<SYSTEM hunchentoot / hunchentoot-1.2.6 / quicklisp 2012-10-13>                
#<SYSTEM hunchentoot-auth / hunchentoot-auth-20101107-git / quicklisp 2012-10-13>
#<SYSTEM hunchentoot-cgi / hunchentoot-cgi-20111105-git / quicklisp 2012-10-13>
#<SYSTEM hunchentoot-test / hunchentoot-1.2.6 / quicklisp 2012-10-13>         
#<SYSTEM hunchentoot-vhost / hunchentoot-vhost-20110418-git / quicklisp 2012-10-13>
```

Comment: What happens if you do the same outside of slimv, I mean in the clisp REPL? Does it work there?

Comment: What Common Lisp implementation?